# How to convert module class name to symbol in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

In a rails initializer file, there is a line for configuring activity objects that accepts symbols like so:

```
config.objects += [ :room, :hotel, ..etc ]
```

These symbols represent classes that I want configured.

My problem is that i'm using a rails engine which defines a 'Blogit::Post' module class which I want to configure. How do I add this to the config array as a symbol?

Comment: What uses `config.objects`?

Comment: it's a ruby initializer file:

`SocialStream.setup do |config|
   ...
   config.objects += [ :room, :hotel, :blogpost ]
   ...
end`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can control camel cases and namespaces in classification of strings by adding underscores or forward slashes to your config.objects.

Forward slashes classify to a namespace:

```
:"blogit/post".classify #=> Blogit::Post
```

Underscores classify to a camelcase:

```
:blogit_post.classify #=> BlogitPost
```

So in your case, the solution would be:

```
config.objects += [ :room, :hotel, :"blogit/post", ..etc ]
```

Or, if you use ruby 2.0, you can use a much cleaner way of array symbol instantiation:

```
config.objects += %i(room hotel blogit/post)
```